# Compilation Error in C++: undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

The command I'm running in Linux terminal is:

```
g++ -c main.cpp fraction.cpp ; g++ -WALL -o main.o fraction.o
```

The full output of what is returned is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-   
gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `main.cpp` was written by my professor, and he is checking our fraction class against it, so the main shouldn't have an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
g++ -WALL -o main.o fraction.o
```

This command instructs your compiler to link `fraction.o` and create a file called `main.o`. Except that `main.o` was, of course, the result of compiling `main.cpp`.

Your obvious intent is to link ***both*** `main.o` and `fraction.o` into a new executable. You need to specify the name of the executable file you wish to create, using the `-o` option, and only ***then*** list both of your object files.

But, of course, you will likely need to recompile `main.cpp`, first.

Comment: Right after the `-o` option. You told your computer that `main.o` is the executable's name. That's what the `-o` option does. For more information, see `gcc`'s documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense